# Turn into, Change to or Become

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

Is this a correct statement?

> As the parameter increases, the distribution **turns** from right-skewed **into** left-skewed.

Or should I use

> As the parameter increases, the distribution **changes** from right-skewed **to** left-skewed.

One can suggest some better alternatives, if possible.

Comment: "Turn into" is synonymous with "change (into)", so generally you can use either.  That being said, I think *changes* sounds better in this context, or perhaps *switches*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are understandable and correct.  My personal choice is

> As the parameter increases, the distribution **changes** from right-skewed to left-skewed.

since *distributions* do not ***turn***, another way to describe it is

> As the parameter increases, the distribution **shifts** from right-skewed to left-skewed.